# Accessing a specific element in an ng-repeat scenario

Tags: javascript, angularjs, scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Morning Stack Overflow,
I am using Angular to populate a bunch of pictures from a JSON file like such:

```
<div class="printDiv" ng-repeat="picture in prints" ng-init="soldOut()">
    <img src="{{picture.source}}" />
</div>
```

In my controller I am trying to grab a specific picture to put a sold out banner over it under certain conditions. I understand that Angular generates a new scope for each new img tag that exists but in my soldOut() function in my controller I am getting a undefined when I try an access the picture:

```
$scope.checkSoldOut = function () {
    console.log($scope.picture);         //returns undefined
}
```

Am I doing something obviously wrong?
Thanks for your time!

Comment: You need to pass picture as a parameter in your soldOut function.  Then console.log(picture.source).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass picture to sold out

```
<div class="printDiv" ng-repeat="picture in prints" ng-init="soldOut(picture)">
    <img src="{{picture.source}}" />
</div>
```

and then in sold out

```
$scope.checkSoldOut = function (picture) {
    console.log(picture);         //returns undefined
}
```